# Automatically show an alert box when browser opens using an Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension for Chrome browser.

I want to make an alert box automatically appear when the browser opens for the first time using this extension (without clicking on the extension icon though).

First time mean normally when i open the chrome double clicking on the icon.

Which JavaScript code should I use?

Comment: That's not my cause Xan. i mean the first time is when i double clicking open the browser normally.not only the very first time after installing the chrome browser.

Comment: Then you can just put your code into the top scope of a background script. It will be loaded at the same time as the browser startup.

Comment: Sorry..how can i do it.what is the meaning of background script ?

Comment: [Overview in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've read google docs you should know about background script. It's declared in manifest like

```
"background": {
"scripts":["background.js"]
},
```

So in your background.js you should use only `alert(something here)`